# How to query data from xml file for a bilingual dictionary

Tags: jquery, xml, input

I am building a bilingual dictionary app. I'm still trying to find out how to: 
query an xml file and get the equivalent word in the 2nd language (which is berber.)
Here is the script:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"languages.xml",
    datatType: "xml",
    success: parseXml,
    failure: function(data){
        alert("XML file could not be found");
    }

});
```

I understand this is where the logic of the app goes. when a user enters, for instance, the word "Ant", and submits, we will fetch the berber equivalent "tagettuft" from the xml file.

```
function parseXml(xml){
    $("input").find("english").each(function(){
        var query =$(this).find("berber").text();
        $("#results").append(query);
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<body>
<form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="search_results.html">
<label for="searchBox">Keyword Search</label>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString">
<button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Submit</button>

</form>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<translations>
<translation>
    <english>Ant</english>
    <berber>Tagettuft</berber>
</translation>
</translations>
```

It doesn't seem to work.
Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your call to the pasrseXml function be success: parseXml(data) ?

Comment: For one thing, I don't see where your `parseXml` method does any parsing at all. 2) a little trick to xml, you can make it a jQuery object and use `.find` on it like any old jQuery Element Object, such as `var txtEng = $(xml).find('translation english').text()`

Comment: @omar Just a quick example of what I was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/q7Xes/

Comment: @SpYk3HH I just tried that. it just prints the word "Ant". but what I'm trying to do is type that word in the input field and get the translation in berber. thx for your comment

Comment: lol @omar, ok I get what you're asking here I think, one sec, answer coming

Comment: @omar added with a full explanation, just comment if you need more understanding of it or help, i'll add jQuery doc link too, one sec

Comment: @omar also, this might be helpful too you -> http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseXml(xml){
    //  Primary: check data isn't empty
    if ($xml) {
        //  first I turn the xml data into a jQuery object to make it easier to search
        var $xml = $(xml);
        //  then I assign our wanted value to a variable
        //  I divided this into parts, simply to show you how you can reach this
        //
        //  however, if you will study jQuery Documentation,
        //      you'll find there are many different
        //      ways to get "inner elements"
        //      and their respective ".text" or ".html"
        var b = $xml.find('english').find('berber').text(), //  use a comma to continue assigning variables
            //  create an input to append to are target div,
            //  this is a traditional way to create a new element in jQuery
            //      simply add the attributes in an object after the string that
            //      determines the type of element you wish to make
            newInput = $('<input />', { readonly: 'readonly', type: 'text', value: b });
        //  add our new input, with it's result to our results area
        $('#results').append(newInput);
    }
};
```

- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

---

***Try using the following for your test***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.1.9.1.min.js" id="jQuery_JS"></script> <!--Your jquery link-->
        <script>
            function parseXml(xml) {
                if (xml) {
                    var $xml = $(xml);

                    console.log('XML:', $xml);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    var sectionEnglish = $xml.find('english');

                    console.log('sectionEnglish:', sectionEnglish);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    var subSectionBerber = sectionEnglish.find('berber');

                    console.log('subSectionBerber:', subSectionBerber);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    var txtBerber = subSectionBerber.text();

                    console.log('txtBerber:', txtBerber);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    var newElement = $('<div />', { text: txtBerber });

                    console.log('newElement:', newElement);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    $('#results').append(newElement);

                    console.log('#results:', $('#results'));
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    console.log('TEST IS COMPLETE');
                }
            }
            $(function() {
                $('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); //  prevent form from normal submission
                    console.log('beging to submit form');
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    var ajaxOptions = {
                            type: "GET",
                            url:"languages.xml",
                            datatType: "xml",
                            success: parseXml,
                            failure: function(data){
                                alert("XML file could not be found");
                            }
                        };

                    console.log('ajaxOptions:', ajaxOptions);
                    console.log(new Array(50).join('-'));

                    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="search_results.html">
            <label for="searchBox">Keyword Search</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString">
            <button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I followed your answer above. I am not getting any error messages from firebug, but there's no output either. Do I need maybe to pass the full path of the xml file? I read this somewhere here in stack overflow.

Comment: @omar make use of `console.log` to help figure out your prob. first, right after making `$xml`, console.log it with `console.log($xml)` and see what it returns. it should appear as a jQuery Element Object in firebug. also, use console.log on other parts like `console.log($('#results').append(newInput)); // will return jquery element obect of div#results, if it finds it!`

Comment: I did what you said and it's not doing anything, blank page even with the console.log.

Comment: @omar i added a full test piece for you, just replace the jquery link with your own and run it

Comment: Hi @SpYk3HH, now I'm getting something from the console, up to 'This test is complete'. but still no output there. Error message: failed to load resource : bad url.  I really appreciate your time to help me here. thanks

Comment: @omar did you see console info for `txtBerber`?

Comment: I can see the tag for txtBerber, but it's empty.

Comment: Hi @SpYk3HH. I added the following lines and I had some results: it returns all the berber words in one string. So I added: var sectionTranslation = $xml.find('translation'); and instead of  var sectionEnglish = $xml.find('english') I substituted:  var sectionEnglish = sectionTranslation.find('english'); I did the same thing with  var subsectionBerber = sectionTranslation.find('berber');

Comment: @omar sounds like you're well on your way to figuring it out.If you need further help and maybe have an example of it online I can look at and help you with, feel free to email me. It's my name at gmail.